# Handling Failed Rollbacks

Tags: design, error-handling

To give an arbitrary example, let's say that I'm storing two objects, `Item` and `Box`, in the same database.

These objects have a one-to-one relationship.

`Item` has the following properties:

- ID (string)
- BoxID (string)
- Price (int)

`Box` has the following properties:

- ID (string)
- ItemID (string)
- ItemLastUpdated (timestamp)

Whenever `Item`'s price changes, `Box`'s `ItemLastUpdated` must be updated as well:

```
try {
    item.price = newPrice;
    itemRepository.Save(item);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle the Exception.
}

try {
    box.itemLastUpdated = now;
    boxRepository.Save(box);        
} catch (Exception e) {
    itemRepository.RollbackLastChange();
    // Handle the Exception.
}
```

My question concerns the scenario where a database outage causes `boxRepository.Save()` to fail.

Because `itemRepository` also uses the same database, it won't be able to rollback its last change.

`item`'s data is now bad because it has stayed modified despite needing a rollback.

***EDIT:***

Our current architecture cannot use transactions because it is using interfaces to work with databases and therefore cannot assume that a given database has transactions built-in.

If we assume that whatever database we use will have transactions, how do we recode the above code to use them? We are currently using different repositories to work with different tables.

Will creating a "master object" to collate all changes and attempt a transaction suffice, or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you use transactions?

Comment: Relevant: [What is atomicity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695323/what-is-the-meaning-of-atomicity-in-dbms)

Comment: @jonrsharpe For this particular project, no.

Comment: @FloatingSunfish if inconsistent data are unacceptable, use database transactions. What is the reason that you can't use transactions? Technical (hard) or policy (soft, can be overridden if needed)?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Transactions are indeed powerful (and designed to handle these scenarios), but our current architecture is treating the database as a blackbox without assuming that it has transactions so we can substitute it with a different one if the need arises.

Comment: Then you will need to do something like [write-ahead-logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging), and recovery on restart. And btw, this can be very error prone, so you might try to prove that it works, e.g. with TLA+ or something.

Comment: @ErikEidt I see, so we really do need to find a way to use transactions somehow... I will try to rephrase my question then. Thanks! :)

Comment: Modeling the concept of transactions isn't a bad thought.  Most databases these days do support them, even some NoSQL databases.  For the ones that don't, you can either make the transaction concept a no-op, or simulate their effect for your database.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice we got from the community, we have decided to alter our architecture to assume that our database technology will know how to use transactions (or some other equivalent).

We will have a master object that transactions will be fed to. These transactions can contain any number of destructive queries (insert, update, delete) in whatever order the client needs them to occur.

The master object will then attempt to execute said transactions which should guarantee that it's an all-or-nothing operation.

Many thanks to everyone who helped!